# Convert GCD to NSOperationqueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

The task can be cancelled if while using `NSOperation` whereas if I use `GCD`, then once I assign the task to queue then we are not able to cancel it, therefore I wonder how could I convert my following implementation in `GCD` to `NSOperation`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
     [self addAllImages];
      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
             [self pageControlSetUp];
             self.fullScreenImageView.hidden = YES;
       });
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
  [self addAllImages];
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    [self pageControlSetUp];
    self.fullScreenImageView.hidden = YES;
  });
}];


[queue addOperation:operation];


//cancel operation
[operation cancel];

//or to cancell all operations
[queue cancelAllOperations];
```

Comment: thanks Inder Kumar. I wonder which is better in terms of performance?

Comment: Clearly GCD is better in terms of performance, because your operations use GCD internally. Also GCD is low level API and NSOperation is high level API. Both has pros and cons. Like in your problem you can't cancel a GCD async block hence you need operations.